# MySql select books by book name and author name

Tags: mysql, select

I have 3 tables,
1) books

```
+----+--------------+------+
| id | name         | code |
+----+--------------+------+
|20  | Lucian house | 2214 +
|21  | Lucian mom   | 2214 |
|22  | GoT          | 2214 |
+----+--------------+------+
```

2) producs_authors

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | book_id | author_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|1   | 20      |    5      |
|2   | 21      |    5      |
|3   | 22      |    7      |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

3) Authors

```
+----+--------------+
| id | name         |
+----+--------------+
| 5  | Marta        |
+----+--------------+
| 7  | Lucian       |
+----+--------------+
```

And i want to select all the books that contain Lucian in name, and all the books that  have as author "Lucian", how can i do this?
Do i need to use a subquery?
Until now i have this (i use yii framework), and this is how criteria looks:

```
SELECT * 
FROM books t 
LEFT JOIN products_authors a ON a.id_book = t.id 
LEFT JOIN authors b ON b.id = a.author_id 
WHERE t.name LIKE %Lucian% 
OR b.name LIKE %Lucian%
```

Comment: i'd always suggest to add the query you tried to do (:

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment .

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: @Strawberry teacher didnt think assignment was worth the effort either.

Comment: Hint: INNER JOIN with WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, a.name
FROM books b
INNER JOIN products_authors pa ON pa.book_id = b.id 
INNER JOIN authors a ON a.id = pa.author_id
WHERE b.name LIKE %Lucian% 
OR a.name LIKE %Lucian%
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this mysql query

```
select id,name from books where name like 'Lucian%' || id IN (select pa.book_id from producs_authors as pa,authors as a where pa.author_id=a.id && a.name= 'Lucian')
```